# Apache Bean 2.4.0 with Apache Flink 1.5

Tags: apache-flink, apache-beam

Is there a place where we can quickly refer and see version compatibility between Apache beam and the runtime environments (Flink, Spark etc). I am learning it the hard way :(. Not sure how many of my issues are contributed by version mismacth.

Currently I am using Beam 2.4.0 and looking at he flink runner pom (https://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.apache.beam%7Cbeam-runners-flink_2.11%7C2.4.0%7Cjar) , it uses flink 1.4.0 jars. So I am assuming Apache beam 2.4.0 works with Apache Flink 1.4.0. Is this correct interpretation?

Unfortunately there is no official docker image for Flink 1.4.0 (https://hub.docker.com/_/flink/)

Answer (score 0):

Flink 1.4.0 is compatible with Beam 2.4.0.
One easy way to find out compatibility is to check the parent pom.xml for Beam release versions and see which Flink version it was tested with. Note that this doesn't mean that it is incompatible with other Flink verions. It may or may not be, you need to find out or ask someone in Beam community.